# How do I get the frequency value by month and the total cost in the same month in the dataset?

Tags: r

How do I get the frequency value by month and the total cost in the same month in the dataset?

This is my dataset

```
install.packages("CASdatasets", repos = "http://dutangc.free.fr/pub/RRepos/", type="source")
library(CASdatasets)
data("itamtplcost") #load the dataset
head(itamtplcost)
names(itamtplcost)
View(itamtplcost)
```

I would like to count the items by the month and get the "total claim size" in the Date column in R.
Below is the output I would like to achieve:

[image]

I tried the below code to get what I want but I can't get the "total claim size".

```
itamtplcost$Date <- as.Date(itamtplcost$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
tab <- table(cut(itamtplcost$Date, 'month'))
monthly_aggre<-data.frame(Date=format(as.Date(names(tab)), '%m/%Y'),
       Frequency=as.vector(tab))
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply.monthly()` function from `xts` package.

```
itamtplcost$Date <- as.Date(itamtplcost$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

library(xts)
df <- as.xts(itamtplcost$UltimateCost, order.by = itamtplcost$Date)

apply.monthly(df, sum)
```

Output

```
                  [,1]
1997-01-08   726986.95
1997-03-18  1651225.47
1997-04-11   895903.67
1997-06-23  3554487.85
1997-07-28  3545689.57
1997-08-29   673680.14
1997-09-27   738011.81
1997-10-02  1008364.26
...
```

To convert this into the required format

```
library(lubridate)

df2 <- data.frame(Month = paste0(month(index(df)), "/",year(index(df))),
                  itamtplcost = df)
rownames(df2) <- NULL
```

OUtput:

```
> df2
      Month itamtplcost
1    1/1997   726986.95
2    3/1997  1222682.37
3    3/1997   428543.10
4    4/1997   258786.06
5    4/1997   637117.61
6    6/1997  1769925.16
7    6/1997   702034.03
8    6/1997  1082528.66
9    7/1997  1005364.03
10   7/1997   780910.04
11   7/1997   429970.06
12   7/1997   700445.53
...
```

Comment: thank you dear but I want to print time period and frequency and total claim size as the previous table in the picture.